# How do I bind my self signed certificate to the domain I bought?

Tags: amazon-web-services, namecheap, self-signed-certificate

I have created a self-signed certificate for the domain I bought, my application is hosted in aws and I am able to point nameservers to the domain.

Next I wanted to add ssl feature in my domain, I am not aware of how this process work.

How do I add my the ssl certificate which is self signed one to the domain I bought from a domain registrar ([namecheap](https://www.namecheap.com/)) and application is hosted in AWS?

Comment: Which service hosts your application in AWS? Is it running behind Cloudfront? A Load balancer? An EC2 instance?

Comment: @JorgRoper an ec2 instance

Answer (score 1):

You have a couple of things to do to get this working:

- You'll need to configure your application in your EC2 instance with
  the self signed certificate.
- You'll need to confirm that your EC2 has a public IP that you can
  point your nameservers to:
  https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/using-instance-addressing.html#concepts-public-addresses
- You'll need to setup access from the internet to the ec2 for
  whichever port your application is running. Instructions on how to
  use a security group to grant this access are here:
  https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/authorizing-access-to-an-instance.html
  (in your case the source IP would probably be 0.0.0.0/0 (ie everyone
  in the world) unless you want to grant that access to specific IPs as
  part of your testing?). If your EC2 is part of a VPC, you'll need to
  make sure your route tables are setup to allow internet access too
  along with a Internet Gateway in the VPC
  (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/VPC_Internet_Gateway.html)

All that said, without understanding your particular use case, this isn't how I'd do this - I'd be using a load balancer and hosting the certificate in ACM while utilising it in the load balancer: https://aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/